# Add UserControls on LayoutControl via Code

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, devexpress

i want to add some UserControls on a LayoutControl via Code. They should appear among each other. And this is the problem. I just become one UserControl to be visible.
I do following at the moment:

```
    foreach (myClass tempMyClass in allObjectsFromMyClass)
    {
        // I create UserControl
        ctrlProgramm programm = new ctrlProgramm();

        // I set some label values and so on for Control
        programm.BxProgrammInitialiseren(tempMyClass);

        // I Add UserControl to the LayoutControl Controls Collection
        LayoutControl.Controls.Add(programm);
    }
```

I just can see the Control which is created in the first loop of the foreach.
Maybe they are recline one over the other? Maybe i need to add a Panel first?

Information: The LayoutControl is in Namespace DevExpress.XtraLayout and we are using DevExpress v2010 vol.2

regards

Comment: What is `LayoutControl`? `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel` or anything else?

Comment: If so, there is a high chance that your `LayoutControl` doesn't `cascade` your added `controls` automatically for you. You may have to learn how to use that `LayoutControl` or try setting the location for your added controls manually using `programm.Left` and `programm.Top` (or `programm.Location`). Your problem may be that **all the added controls have the same `Location` and `Size`**, so you thought there was only 1 visible. (in fact, they're overlapped).

Comment: @KingKing Hey thanks you are right. The controls are overlapped. I used a PanelControl on the LayoutControl and using the Dock Propertie of the Controls. So it is working fine now :) thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding controls into LayoutControl **you should wrap these controls with LayoutControlItems** as follows:

```
//Create a layout item and add it to the root group.    
LayoutControlItem item1 = layoutControl.Root.AddItem();

item1.Name = "item1";
ctrlProgramm programm = new ctrlProgramm();

// Set the item's Control and caption.    
item1.Control = programm;
item1.Text = "Program:";
```

Related help articles:
[How to: Create layout items via code](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2251)
[How to: Create layout groups and items via code](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2252)

To learn more about the LayoutControl concepts please refer the following articles:
[Introducing the XtraLayoutControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3407)
[Tutorial: Creating a Simple Layout](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2322)